# Cannot evaluate com.android.okhttp.HttpUrl$Builder.toString()

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, okhttp

The following code seems to cause this exception to be thrown:

```
public static String GET(String url) throws Exception {
    URL obj = new URL(url);
    HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) obj.openConnection();
    con.setRequestMethod("GET");
    if (con.getResponseCode() == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {  <--**Here**
      ....
    }
```

.....
}

This is the method in the MainActivity that calls this function:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    new AsyncTask<Void,Void,List<Client>>(){
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(List<Client> clients) {
            super.onPostExecute(clients);
            myList=clients;
        }

        @Override
        protected List<Client> doInBackground(Void... voids) {
            return getClients();

        }
    }.execute();

    if(myList == null)
    Log.v("Tag", "its null");
    else
        Log.v("Tag", "it works");
}

public List<Client> getClients() {
    List<Client> result = new ArrayList<Client>();
    try {
        String str = PHPtools.GET(WEB_URL + "Client.php");
        JSONArray array = new JSONObject(str).getJSONArray("Client");
        for (int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++) {
            JSONObject jsonObject = array.getJSONObject(i);
            Client client = new Client();
            client.setLastName(jsonObject.getString("lastName"));
            client.setFirstName(jsonObject.getString("firstName"));
            client.setId(jsonObject.getInt("_id"));
            client.setPhoneNumber(jsonObject.getString("phoneNumber"));
            client.setEmail(jsonObject.getString("email"));
            client.setCreditCardNumber(jsonObject.getLong("creditCardNumber"));

            result.add(client);
        }
        return result;

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
```

}

The URL I am passing has been tested and works fine. I tried it on Chrome and the JSON I am trying to parse displays perfectly fine.
but the problem starts when trying to establish connection at the line mentioned above.
I am calling this method from an AsyncTask and also added an Internet permission to the Manifest file.
This is the full error I am receiving:
"Method threw 'java.lang.NullPointerException' exception. Cannot evaluate com.android.okhttp.HttpUrl$Builder.toString()"

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please add the _exact_ error message and point out the _exact_ line of code it is raised.

Comment: I did that already. This is the line:
 if (con.getResponseCode() == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK)

Error:  "Method threw 'java.lang.NullPointerException' exception. Cannot evaluate com.android.okhttp.HttpUrl$Builder.toString()"